# division by a number of multiplication of integers of an array and take the modulo

Tags: arrays, math, modulo

I came to this question which is like following

you have an array of n integers ( integers can be as large as 10^9) and you have q queries, every query has one index of the array so you have to multiply the array without the integer of that particular index and then you have one number, m, then, you have to take modulo by this number m(which  can be up to 10^9) and give the result for each query.

```
e.g. suppose you have an array of n = 5 integers
            1,2,3,4,5
and you have q = 3 queries 1,3, 5 and mod value m = 100.
for 1st query: (2*3*4*5) mod 100 = 20
for 2nd query: (1*2*4*5) mod 100 = 40
for 3rd query: (1*2*3*4) mod 100 = 24
so output is 20,40,24
```

I don't want code just tell me the approach which should be optimal.

Comment: In the actual question is m prime?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the relationship between m and the integers in the list. Is m prime? Is m relatively prime to all the numbers in the list? If either one is so, there is a fast and simple algorithm. If not or you do not know, the best algorithm is slower but still doable.

Comment: No, m is not prime

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the product of all the ints in the array. Store that.

```
int product = 1*2*3*4*5;
```

Now for each query, your calculation is simply

```
(product/query) %100;
```

Comment: The product can become very big very fast. Simple integer data types will not suffice and BigIntegers will be quite slow.

Comment: I said integer can be as large as 10^9 so the product of all these integers will lead to overflow so this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one solution which involves recursively using the modulus operator on relatively small numbers. This solution may take a long time to compute, but it should be able to easily avoid the type of overflow that you are experiencing.

We can exploit the following property of modular arithmetic:

```
(a*b) mod c = ((a mod c)*b) mod c
```

See below for a simple example. It uses relatively small numbers (far smaller than the overflow you would experience) but it demonstrates the point.

---

```
(5*4*3*2*1) mod 7
```

Computing this the "traditional way" you would just do:

```
120 mod 7 = 1
```

But, let's say we can't use numbers as large as 120.

We can do this:

```
(5) mod 7 = 5   (take this result as input to next line)
            |
            |
 +----------+
 |
 |
(5*4) mod 7 = 20 mod 7 = 6 
                         |
                         |
 +-----------------------+
 |
 |
(6*3) mod 7 = 18 mod 7 = 4
                         |
                         |
 +-----------------------+
 |
 |
(4*2) mod 7 = 8 mod 7 = 1
                        |
                        |
 +----------------------+
 |
 |
(1*1) mod 7 = 1 mod 7 = 1  <--this is final result
```

Note how the final result above (`1`) is the same result by just doing the calculation `120 mod 7` directly. However, the largest number we used in any calculation was only `20`.

One more thing to note: For this method, if any intermediate result is ever `0`, then the final result must be `0` also.

---

**EDIT**

If you need to deal with even smaller numbers, you can use the following property of modular arithmetic (which is really just an extension of what is already shown above):

```
a*b mod c = ((a mod c)*(b mod c)) mod c
```

By doing this, instead of dealing with numbers as large as `a*b`, you will only deal with numbers as large as `(a mod c)*(b mod c)`, which must be less than or equal to `(c-1)^2` (since `x mod c` must be less than or equal to `c-1`). Of course, the tradeoff for dealing with even smaller numbers is that your code will be more complicated and take slightly longer to execute.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is another option then.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of to possibly speed up computation time (but increase memory usage) is for your program to utilize a database (or even just a text file) that stores a lookup table of solutions to modulus operations. So instead of your program needing to calculate modulus each time, it just looks up the value in a text file.